# CanExecuteChanged not working properly

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a CanExecuteChanged event handler.

I have an abstract class that implements ICommand:

```
public abstract class CommandBase<TViewModel> : ICommand
{
    protected TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    protected CommandBase(TViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
}
```

then I have a command that inherits from this base command:

```
public class AddNewFilmWindowCommand : CommandBase<ViewModelCollection<FilmModel>>
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public AddNewFilmWindowCommand(ViewModelCollection<FilmModel> viewModelCollection)
        : base(viewModelCollection)
    {
    }

    public override void Execute(object item)
    {
        this.ViewModel.NewItem = new FilmModel();

        var onCanExecuteChanged = this.CanExecuteChanged;
        if (onCanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            onCanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.ViewModel.NewItem == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but the CanExecuteChanged is giving me warning:

> Warning   CS0108  'AddNewFilmWindowCommand.CanExecuteChanged' hides inherited member 'CommandBase>.CanExecuteChanged'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. SpravaFilmu.ViewModels

and is always null. It never goes grayed after I click on the button using this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the event in `CommandBase` abstract.

```
    public abstract event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
```

The UI framework you are using likely only knows about `ICommand`. Since your subclass doesn't override the event, the UI is going to bind to the event in base class. When you click the button it will raise the event in the subclass but not the base class. Basically you have 2 events here - the UI references one of them, but you are raising the other one.

Comment: Hi, thank you, this solved the issue :) perfect! I will remember this for the next time!

Answer (score 0):

`AddNewFilmWindowCommand` inherits from `CommandBase`. They both have the event `CanExecuteChanged`, and in the command base it's not abstract or virtual. If you intended it to override the event from the base class then use the new keyword:

```
public class AddNewFilmWindowCommand : CommandBase<ViewModelCollection<FilmModel>>
{
    public new event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time. I have tried this and still the result is NULL so it will never pass the if statement :( so I wonder what originally set EventHandler to something? I have another referenced project where the event handler is set in the if statement to something already.

Answer (score 0):

You can't raise an event in a base class... but you could have a protected method to do so... so in `CommandBase` add:

```
protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
  CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

And then in your implementation, just do not declare the event, and call it like:

```
public override void Execute(object item)
{
  this.ViewModel.NewItem = new FilmModel();
  RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```